# В каком случае употреблять чищеНый/чищеННый

Tags: орфография

Почему в предложении ниже слово *чище**нн**ые* пишется с двумя Н:

```
На своих громадных ногах он носил полушелковые чулки и широкие башмаки, неизвестно когда чищенные.
```

В то же время, в словосочетании:

```
чищеные орехи
```

употребляется слово *чище**н**ые* с одной Н.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В первом примере  страдательное причастие прошедшего времени, а втором - прилагательное.
  В первом случае сохраняется глагольное значение (налицо временной предел) определение выражено причастием; во втором случае назван признак постоянный.

Подробнее здесь:

[Н и НН в причастиях и отглагольных прилагательных](http://www.gramma.ru/RUS/?id=4.35)

[Двойное н и одно н в суффиксах страдательных причастий прошедшего времени и соотносительных с ними прилагательных.   Полные формы](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=52#pp52)